# Xpath with same ID - how can I grab 2nd element?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

I'm facing a problem with grabbing value from page, in frame that I operate there are 3 xpath with same ID and I cannot use more precise one - or dont know how to do it.

I already tried adding [0] or [1] after xpath but it doesn't worked out like:

`Temp_Pass = WebDriverWait(driver,9000).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//td[@id='content-main-rowOdd']")[0])).text`

and

`Temp_Pass = WebDriverWait(driver, 9000).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//td[@id='content-main-rowOdd']/following-sibling::tr[1]"))).text`

but both method doesn't worked

Here is code from frame on website:

```
  <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td id="content-main-rowOdd">For user zxc the fallowing pass     has been generated:</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <td id="content-main-rowOdd">
       abcd
         <div></div>
      </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <td id="content-main-rowOdd">
         <input id="content-main-button-default" type="submit" onlick="window.close()" name="command-cancel" value="cancel">
         <input id="content-main-button-default" type="submit" name="command-next" value="Next">
      </td>
      </tr>
      .....
      </tbody>
```

What I would like to get is "abcd"
But I only was able to grab: "For user zxc the following pass     has been generated:"

Comment: I dont know why code from website was not posted in my post...
<tbody>
   <tr>
     <td id="content-main-rowOdd">For user zxc the fallowing pass     has been generated:</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td id="content-main-rowOdd">
      abcd
       <div></div>
   </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td id="content-main-rowOdd">
      <input id="content-main-button-default" type="submit" onlick="window.close()" name="command-cancel" value="cancel">
      <input id="content-main-button-default" type="submit" name="command-next" value="Next">
   </td>
   </tr>
   .....
   </tbody>

Comment: get all of them to python's list and later get from list `all_items[1]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Since the `<td>` elements are in separate `<tr>` elements, if the expected element is inside the second `<tr>` element then you can try this: `"//table/tr[2]/td[@id='content-main-rowOdd']"`
   In code:

   ```
   Temp_Pass = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//table/tr[2]/td[@id='content-main-rowOdd']"))).text
   ```
2. Get all the elements using `find_elements_by_` and then get the text from the second element.

   ```
   list = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//td[@id='content-main-rowOdd']")));
   Temp_Pass = list[1].text
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the XPath that you need in order to get the 2nd element. You can use `[2]` on the XPath selector, but its a little weird in use.

```
Temp_Pass = WebDriverWait(driver,9000).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "(//td[@id='content-main-rowOdd'])[2]"))).text
```

Notice that the XPath contains brackets and then we select the 2nd item returned from that XPath.

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there. As the text **abcd** is associated with the text **For user zxc the fallowing pass has been generated:**, an easy approach to extract the text **abcd** would be to identify the node with text as *For user ...* and then identify the desired node inducing *WebDriverWait* for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and then extract the desired text as follows:

```
print(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//td[@id='content-main-rowOdd' and contains(., 'generated')]//following::tr[1]/td[@id='content-main-rowOdd']"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
```

**Note** : You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```